# Common word for Fan's horn

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the widespread word to name the mouthpiece used by fans at the stadium?

[image]

Comment: I would call it a bullhorn.

Comment: Yeah, a *bullhorn* is a hollow conical device which, without any sort of amplification, directs the voice.  A *megaphone* is a device which serves the same purpose but which employs a microphone, amplifier, and loudspeaker.

Comment: @HotLicks - No. Both terms refer to the same thing and both predate electronic amplification. Only the obsolete *speaking trumpet* would refer solely to an unamplified device.

Comment: If it weren't for the picture, I'd be suggesting a vuvuzela.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [megaphone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaphone) or **loud hailer**. They are commonly used at outdoor political rallies.

Comment: I'm going to guess that *loud hailer* is common in some non-US variant of English. In USA English, I've only ever heard *megaphone* and *bullhorn*.

Comment: I think "loud hailer" is probably a nautical term.

Comment: I think the problem for the British is they like neither of the words 'mega' or 'bull'